# Div loses height in angular app - background cover stops working

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, background

I had a simple html app that used a background cover image.  The following code worked fine.

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
}

.mainBody{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("/images/background.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
}
```

However, when i created a simple angular app w/bootstrap and used the same code, the mainBody div lost its height component and the image fails to show.

The html is simple and straightforward:

index.html

```
<body ng-app="testApp">
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

root.html

```
<div class="mainBody">

  <div class="navTitle">
    <span class="title">Recordings</span>
  </div>

  <div class="navMenu">
    <!-- <span class="fa fa-twitter menu twitter"></span> -->
    <span class="menu">About</span>
    <span class="menu">Podcasts</span>
    <span class="menu">Support</span>
  </div>  

</div>
```

The same root.html works in a simple html file.  And I've debugged the angular app to see if there are any additional css being added for body and mainBody and have not found any.  Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned the order of adding your own style-sheet in the html. If you have added the bootstrap file below your custom css file then the problem may be occurred due to the over-right issue of css. 
So first add your bootstrap file and then add your custom css. 
If you have already done with this then please provide your html div.

Comment: Thanks Biswajit.  I tried that and it still did not work.  I've added the html code in the question.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

body finds it's parent div that is html. So the html needs a proper height.